# Mapbox Icon image hover issue

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Using Mapbox, I am trying to create multiple icons on map, I've succeeded placing the icons, but the clickable area of these icons is not accurate unless I zoom in very close into the icons. I don't want to zoom in too much for clicking on it. Is there any way to improve the hover/click area accuracy for such condition.

```
JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/parveenkaloi/tz6akvqd/96/
```

Thank You

Comment: Unable to see your example due error: `Failed to load http://demo.io-productions.com/2DMap_v2/resources/sprite/icons@2x.json: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.`

Comment: Thanks for reply... Please try now... there was some error..